# Third level domain with www

Tags: url, iis, dns, windows-server

We have a website displaying some weather data, which can be accessed using a second level domain name: weather.ourdomain.org

Now, the marketing department has just released a brochure with a typo, where the url is listed as www.weather.ourdomain.org

What can we do to make it work? We have a Windows server with IIS where weather.ourdomain.org is configured.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to configure weather.ourdomain.org as a subdomain. You can then put an A record at the Apex (weather.ourdomain.org)so it still points to whatever it points to now, and have another A record / CNAME registered at www

Obviously this all depends on whoever it is that is the registrar for your domain name and whether they allow sub domains. If they don't you can probably register Azure DNS or some other DNS service to actually run your Nameservers.

Who is your registrar? we can probably tell you what they allow.

Comment: Thank you! We have just done as you suggested (added the A record/CNAME), and now it's working fine.